# Restrict date input for specific intervale of time

Tags: html, date, input, tags, restriction

I am building a React App, and tho it has no connection with React, I wanna allow the user to pick only one day within the next two weeks with an `input[type="date"]` tag.

I don't know how to restrict the `input` only to a specific period of time (e.g. the next 14 days).

Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am building a React App, and tho it has no connection with React

What does this mean? You created a React project but aren't using React?

There are several options to do this, [react-datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker) and [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) are my favorite for creating a date picker and creating custom date constraints.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-l5vu3z?file=src/App.js) is a stackblitz of limiting a raw input to two weeks from now.

```
let twoWeeks = new Date(Date.now() + 12096e5)
.toISOString()
.split('T')[0]
.toLocaleString([], {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'numeric',
  day: 'numeric',
});

<input type="date" max={twoWeeks} />
```

Comment: I meant that there might be not anything related to React specifically and that it maybe can be done in Vanilla.js